# Import library into eclipse non gradle project

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am very new to Android development. I am not using gradle. I want to use the following [library](https://github.com/Yalantis/Context-Menu.Android)

Can you please let me know how to include in my project.

1. When I clone your project to eclipse(Mars) it is showing the following structure-

[image: context menu]

2. My project structure is given below.

[image: my app]

Now shall I copy the "lib" folder (lib\src\main...) to my "src" folder?
Normally I add the library like the following way-

[image: adding library]

Answer (score 0):

Just import the lib folder of the library instead of the whole library in Eclipse. And add it as a library to your project.

Comment: Thanks Deepak. So I should copy lib/src/main/.. folder to libs folder in my project?

Comment: you can copy all the source files into your project src directory.